# Resources exceeded during query execution: Too many DML statements outstanding against table [dataset.table-name], limit is 20

Tags: google-cloud-platform

### I'm met error when DML to bigquery, please support me explain or any document to resolve problem.
Thank you so much

java.lang.RuntimeException: [BigQueryError{reason=resourcesExceeded, location=null, message=Resources exceeded during query execution: Too many DML statements outstanding against table rare-chiller-170104:adrepo.dsp_google_ads_asset_master, limit is 20}][BigQueryError{reason=resourcesExceeded, location=null, message=Resources exceeded during query execution: Too many DML statements outstanding against table rare-chiller-170104:adrepo.dsp_google_ads_asset_master, limit is 20}]

Answer (score 1):

The error you see is related to the limit of concurrent DML operations submitted against the table `dsp_google_ads_asset_master`. As documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#update_delete_merge_dml_concurrency), when a DML operation is running against a table BigQuery queues other ones that are submitted in Pending state. From the error message you observed it seems that you have reached the concurrency limit for the pending jobs that is 20.

This concurrency limit is applied per table so, unfortunately, using batch or interactive queries will not solve this problem. The only workaround I can think of is to take into account this restriction and control the number of submitted DML jobs. If this is a heavy restriction for your use-case you can contact [GCP technical support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs#contacting_technical_support) and consult if this limit (20) can be increased for your project.